# Implementing Abstract Methods in PHP error

Tags: php, oop, abstract

I have created a class here that contains an abstract method , it always return this errors to me even though that method is declared abstract. Here's my whole code

```
<?php
interface Validator{
    public function isValid($input);
    public function getErrors();
}

class Validator_AbstractValidator
{
    protected $_errors = array();

    abstract public function isValid($input);

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->_errors;
    }

    protected function _addError($message){
        $this_errors[] = $message;
    }
}

class Validator_MinimumLength extends Validator_AbstractValidator
{
    protected  $_minLength;

    public function __construct($minLength)
    {
        $this_minLength = $minLength;
    }

    public function isValid($input){
         if (strlen($input) > $this->_minLength) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->_addError("Input must be at least {$this_minLength}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Validator_NoSpaces extends Validator_AbstractValidator{

    public function isValid($input) {
        if (preg_match('/\s/', $input)){
            $this->_addError("Spaces are not allowed");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}


interface Form_ElementInterface extends Validator{ }

class Form_Element_AbstractElement extends Validator_AbstractValidator implements Form_ElementInterface
{

    protected $_validators = array();

    public function addValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->_validators[] = $validator;
    }

    public function getValidators()
    {
        return $this->_validators;
    }

    protected function _addErrors(array $errors)
    {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $this->_addError($error);
        }
    }

    public function hasErrors()
    {
        return (count($this->getErrors()) !== 0);
    }

    public function isValid($input)
    {
        foreach ($this->_validators as $validator) {
            if (!$validator->isValid($input)) {
                $this->_addErrors($validator->getErrors());
            }
        }
        return !$this->hadErrors();
    }
}

class Form_Element extends Form_Element_AbstractElement
{
    public function __construct($value,$minLength = 8)
    {
        $this->addValidator(new Validator_NoSpaces($value));
        $this->addValidator(new Validator_MinimumLength($minLength));
        //...
    }
}
```

The error is this Fatal error: Class Validator_AbstractValidator contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Validator_AbstractValidator::isValid) in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\Validator.php on line 21

but line 21 only contains this

```
}
```

Is there anything I've missed?

Even though I added the keyward abstract in Class Validator_AbstractValidator class I encountered this problem

```
Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function Validator::isValid() (previously declared abstract in Validator_AbstractValidator) in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\Validator.php on line 57
```

but once again line 57 only contains this

```
{
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PHP 5 introduces abstract classes and methods. It is not allowed to
>   create an instance of a class that has been defined as abstract. Any
>   class that contains at least one abstract method must also be
>   abstract. Methods defined as abstract simply declare the method's
>   signature they cannot define the implementation.

if a class is not declared as abstract, it cannot contain any abstract methods.

```
abstract class Validator_AbstractValidator
{
    //...
}
```

**Update:**

```
class Form_Element_AbstractElement extends Validator_AbstractValidator implements Form_ElementInterface
```

You are extending an abstract class (Validator_AbstractValidator) and also implementing the interface `Validator` all together, that is not possible.

Extend the class and implement the interface individually and implement the interface `Validator` in a separate class, not in `Validator_AbstractValidator` because it's an abstract class you've already declared before.

**Implementing of interface Validator:**

```
class from_validator_interface implement Validator{
    // you have to implement all the methods declared in the interface, in your case
    // `isValid` and `getErrors` both methods have to be implemented
}
```

**Extending of abstract class Validator_AbstractValidator:**

```
class someClass extends Validator_AbstractValidator{
    // you don't need to implement all the abstract methods like interface
}
```

**Some usefull links:** [**php.net**](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGEQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php&ei=-mXoT5gFgqusB8jEnOsI&usg=AFQjCNEHRkWLi053BRt1HwvEGdBm8FgH3g&sig2=zwYNB1Wf62sZV_G82XV4bQ), [**other**](http://blog.motane.lu/2012/01/21/multiple-inheritance-in-php/) and [**more**](http://www.sunilb.com/php-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me once I add `abstract` to `Validator_AbstractValidator`, which you say you already did.

```
abstract class Validator_AbstractValidator
{ ...
```

Comment: I already added it but i gave me this error Can't inherit abstract function Validator::isValid() (previously declared abstract in Validator_AbstractValidator) in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\Validator.php on line 57

Comment: It sounds like the code you're testing doesn't match what you posted. I can reproduce that error by making `Form_Element_AbstractElement` abstract and redeclaring `isValid` as abstract.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with the following code :

```
Interface Fruit
{
   public function getCalories() ;
   public function countSeeds() ;
}

Interface Vegetable
{
   public function getVitamins() ;
   public function getCalories() ;
}

class Tomato implements Fruit, Vegetable
{
   ...
}
```

Here was my solution, I added a third parent interface.

```
Interface Food 
{
    public function getCalories() ;
}

Interface Fruit extends Food
{

   public function countSeeds() ;
}

Interface Vegetable extends Food
{
   public function getVitamins() ;
}

class Tomato implements Fruit, Vegetable
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If this adds value consider extending the question as this is not an answer.